# Accepting single dynamic, but unused, element in route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, url-routing

I want to accept URLs for my objects that contain an element that is not used, but which would be nice for SEO reasons. For example, I want to accept an url like:

`http://localhost:3000/people/USA/123-joe-schmoe`

.. where the "/USA" bit has no significance at all, other than signaling to users and search engines that this person resides in the USA.

I've tried setting up my rule using globbing, as well as for example doing something like

`match "people/:whatever/:id"     => "people#show", :constraints => {:id => /\d+-.*/}, :as => "person"`

But this results in an attempt to route to `:controller => people, :action => "show", :whatever => #<Person id: 123 ...>` which fails.

Is it possible to have the routing ignore the :whatever part and pass in my :id in stead?

Answer (score 0):

You can try a widcard match instead

```
match "people/*/:id => "doctors#show", :constraints=> {:id=>/\d+=.*/}, :as=>"person"
```